# The source code breakpoint settings decompressed by maven-dependency-plugin in IDEA are invalid

Tags: intellij-idea

I wrote a project here, the structure is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE4f2.png)

In the development environment, the framework only loads the resources in the classes directory. Because of the multi-module development, some other modules are all decompressed to the classes directory through the maven-dependency-plugin plugin.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-xxx-xxxx-api</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeGroupIds>com.xxx.xxxx.addons.mall</includeGroupIds>
                            <includeArtifactIds>xxx-xxx-api</includeArtifactIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                 </executions>
              </plugin>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTNhz.png)

At this point, when debug runs, there will be a problem that all class files decompressed by maven-dependency-plugin cannot be debugged, and non-maven-dependency-plugin methods can be debugged. How to solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlpfQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30W7n.png)

Comment: For the class to be a debuggable - it must be compiled with the debug info. So make sure that if the classes you copy are produced by Maven - they were compiler with [debug info](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#debug) enabled.

Comment: The debug parameter is true by default, no need to set it